# Garbage collector - behavior when I have declared a static list

Tags: c#

I have one important question for you. I declared private static list this way

```
private static List<structType> myList = new List<structType>();
```

My application works all the time, and I'm wondering what will be with this list when GC will work.
I add data to this list in specyfic services and I keet it about many minutes and next it deleted. Of course this data are keeping to specific service and after the service I deleted this data.

I'm looking for information how will it behave garbage collector because I don't want deleted this data earlie and lose reference to this list.

I'm not sure that I good understand behavior GC, and if you have any information please share it.

Thanks :)

I know that my solutions is not good but sometimes I need keep specyfic information that other service may have been performed. This way relates to a specific case.

Comment: Your list is not static. Please update

Comment: Sorry, I corrected :)

Comment: In general, if you have an object, you don't have to worry about the GC removing it if you intend to reference it later. It only removes things that aren't going to be referenced (unless you do something crazy). I'd say in day to day development, the GC rarely is a concern that you need to worry about. The GC generally gets out of your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Garbage will not collect things that have "a unbroken chain of strong references to a application root". If that check is true, the GC asumes you are working with it and will not touch it.

If that is no longer the case the GC may collect it - eventually. With a permanently running application, a alternate GC strategy may be adviseable. When the GC runs, all other threads must pause. So it runs realy rarely. As your application runs for a exceptional time, a alternate GC strategy may be adviseable. The server one might be a good starting point - but it sounds like it is one anyway.

There is a odd intermediate case, the `WeakReference<T>`. It will not keep something in memory when the GC goes around "collecting free space". But if it was *not yet* collected, you can get a strong reference again. It is one of the caching options.

Comment: While I don't write null to my list GC will not move the list even  when I will have a empty list. Do I understand good ?

Comment: @Andreas As long as you hold a strong reference (in something that itself has a chain of strong references), the GC will not touch it. Maybe move the location in memory, but as long as you do not go down to handling naked pointers, that does not mater. | There is no book, as there are only few ways to skin that particular feline. The terminology might differ slightly, but .NET does it largely the same as Java: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals | Just under MAC, they use Reference Counting instead of a GC.

Answer (score 1):

static fields are GC roots, so:

- the list is reachable (via the static field) throughout the lifetime of the app
- which means the array behind the list is reachable
- the value-types live directly in the array

So: nothing to worry about (except perhaps thread-safety, but that is a separate issue)

---

As a general rule: if you could even *notice* that it has been collected: it can't be collected. This excludes noticing indirectly via a "finalizer", and anything involving `WeakReference`.

Comment: "except perhaps thread-safety" can you give more information about this issue. I read more with pleasure :)

Comment: @Andreas He meant race conditions, wich only happen once you start with Multitasking, but happens for all flavors of Multitasking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition | Lists do not even have a Concurrent variant. Their very design does not work in multitasking. Queues, Stacks, Bags and Dicionaries however have concurrent versions. Some have several.

Comment: @Andreas a static field is inherently visible to multiple threads; if it is never mutated after the static constructor of your type, then: fine - but if threads are ever adding/removing/changing/etc the items in some way: you need to synchronize, as otherwise there are no guarantees of correctness - you'll start seeing all kinds of oddness